# multipart/form-data post request getting CORS error with Angular 7 and spring boot, only when image size is more than 1 mb

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, multipartform-data

I have a spring boot application where the controller is consuming the post request of content-type "multipart/form-data". This code is working when the image size is less than 1MB but if I upload any image of size more than 1MB, I always encounter this error. This error only appears in the production environment. In the local system, this is working perfectly fine.
Error [image: cors error in the browser console when calling the API]

I have already increased the default size of the multipart file max size in the spring boot application property file.

```
#Spring max size upload
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
    
#Server properties
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=100000000
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100000000
```

Here is the Spring boot controller
[image: Spring boot controller]

Comment: it's working in local ?

Comment: Yes, It's working locally. When I run both Angular Front end and backend in the local system.

Comment: Check your could provider

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Because the same endpoint works when I upload the small size image. But when choosing the image with size 1mb or more it throws this CORS error in production.

Comment: Check your production app deployed  server configuration and if you're using load balancer check the config also

Comment: Thanks, Rajesh. I checked the Nginx configuration for file upload and found it was just 1MB and that was the issue I updated it and it started working.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this same issue locally also. I have spring-boot application with the default tomcat. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Nginx for the load balancing that was the issue. When I increase the size of Nginx from AWS. The error got resolved.

I followed this blog to increase the size. You must need the root permission to update your Nginx configuration file

https://medium.com/@ghazaltaimur27/change-file-upload-limit-in-ngnix-in-aws-server-2820c491e9a4